# Error when using "angular 2-google-chart"

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use this module " [angular2-google-chart](https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart)".

But when  start the application,  get this error:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive.ts
>   Module build failed: Error: /home/user/Desk/project/frontend/node_modules/angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file
>   seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published
>   libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
>   issue inthe library repository to alert its author and ask them to
>   package the library using the Angular Package Format
>   (`/goo.gl/jB3GVv`).
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/user/Desk/project/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
>       at plugin.done.then (/home/user/Desk/project/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)

How to fix this error?

Comment: Iam posted answer please try and let me know if any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error path problem. You have to copy that `angular2-google-chart.directive.ts`file and paste some your project folder like assets or anything then import use it problem solve.

Here is an working Example Demo for you iam maded from you mentioned  "[angular2-google-chart](https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart)"

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zp46ve

Installation:-

```
npm install angular2-google-chart
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>  
        // !important: You want to give this variable(var googleLoaded = false;). This is used to run multiple chart in your jade.
        var googleLoaded = false;
        // !important: Define which chart packages to preload.Because this package uses ChartWrappers you can use any chart type that Google supports, but if it // isn't loaded it will load it on demand. 
        var googleChartsPackagesToLoad = ['geochart'];
    </script>
    </head>
```

app.module.ts

```
import {GoogleChart} from './angular2-google-chart.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GoogleChart
  ],...
```

Output Screenshot,

[image]

I hope it's help you to start.
If any error let me know.